# Automatically Boot into Ubuntu without Live CD

Tags: boot, server, grub2

I am trying to boot into my Ubuntu server and after updates, I can now only boot in with a live Ubuntu CD in the Grub terminal with these commands:

```
grub> set pager=1
grub> set root=(hd1,gpt2)
grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
grub> initrd /initrd.img
grub> boot
```

Once I boot in and try to reinstall grub with this command:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

I get this error:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

I have tried boot-repair with recommended options, but I get this warning:

```
GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted 
filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as
Gparted. Then try again.
```

Gparted results:

```
Partition    File System    Mount Point    Label    Size      Flags    
/dev/sda1    fat16                         Ubuntu   512MiB    boot
/dev/sda2    ext4           /                       927GiB 
/dev/sda3    linux-swap                             3.91GiB
```

I am tempted to reinstall Ubuntu altogether, but that is my last resort. Ubuntu is the only OS on the machine, this is not a dual-boot. Any help in determining how to automatically boot into the Ubuntu server would be greatly appreciated! I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: This happens because you installed grub to your LiveCD, not to your HDD.

Comment: I tried that, but I am still getting the same boot-repair warning message as stated above. I even tried giving it the suggested bios_grub flag. Do I need to reformat /dev/sda1 to be unformatted as boot-repair is suggesting?

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem, I was trying to install grub in the wrong root directory. Instead of:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

I did:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/ /dev/sda
```